# C# Capturing the first match with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got an input string that looks like this:

```
url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fsale-deal%3Futm_source%3Dinsider-primary-action%3Dinsider-primary-action&amp;utm_source=FB
```

or

```
url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fsale&amp;utm_source=FB&amp;sub_id1=M12
```

the string sometimes has or non `%3Futm_source`

how to get link between url= and `%3Futm_source%` or `&amp;utm_source`

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"url=(https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com[a-zA-Z0-9-_/%\.]+)%3Futm_source|&amp;utm_source");
                    Match result = reg.Match(inPut);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value));
```

it always get from `url=` to `&amp;utm_source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
(?<=url=).*?(?=%3Futm_source|&amp;utm_source)
```

- `(?<=url=)` Positive look behind. matches `url=`.
- `.*` - Matches anything except new line.
- `(?=%3Futm_source|&amp;utm_source)` - Positive look ahead. Matches `%3Futm_source` or `&amp;utm_source`

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3durl%3d%29.*%3f%28%3f%3d%253Futm_source%7c%26amp%3butm_source%29&i=url%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fsale-deal%253Futm_source%253Dinsider-primary-action%253Dinsider-primary-action%26amp%3butm_source%3dFB%0d%0a%0d%0aurl%3dhttps%25fhjkfghjkghj%26utm_source)

Comment: Sorry, I edited question `&amp;utm_source` not &utm_source